# Xamarin.Forms dynamically add controls without layout

Tags: xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

I'm a newcomer to Xamarin, coming from iOS, where I do most of my laying out of views in code by doing my own simple math and positioning views via what I've heard called the "springs and struts" method. I'm trying to do everything in the master project with no platform specific code. I've messed around with laying out views via XAML, but now I want to try doing it purely through code. The problem is that I can't find anything in the docs for doing this.

Is there really no way to just put a view at a given location without using a layout (as opposed to doing something convoluted like using a `StackLayout` and using the margins to hack a position out of it, or using a `RelativeLayout` and using constraints)? I find it hard to believe that there wouldn't be, and if there isn't, I feel like that's enough for me to consider the platform broken.

As an extension to this question, is it impossible for views to directly contain other views? Put another way, does every view the view hierarchy tree correspond in a leaf node and all non-leaf nodes have to be layouts?

Seems like a weird design decision and far too constricting.

Comment: Yes, a View generally needs to be contained in a Layout.  Some views can contain others views, and some cannot.  It would be helpful if you had a specific example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm just looking for a general solution, but the specific thing I'm trying to do at the moment is to take an image, proportionally scale it to fit the screen height, but have it horizontally slightly off center from the screen center, the amount of which is dependent on how much it was scaled to fit the screen height.

Comment: Plus do that all independent of device screen scale, analogously to iOS's coordinate system of points.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, rootview of the xaml pages has to be a Layout deriving class.

Use AbsoluteLayout if you want to position views at given coordinates.

Comment: I think this looks to be what I want, but I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to use it to get the effect I'm after. Could you provide an example laying out a `BoxView` with the x and y coordinate relative to the width of the layout, width an absolute value, and the height proportional to the layout height? I haven't been able to find any examples showing how to set different `LayoutFlags` for each value of the `LayoutBounds`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but a basic way that comes to my mind is adding the absolute layout as the page content, and then subscribe to its "SizeChanged" event. Inside the callback you cast the sender to absolutelayout and get its Width and Height property. Then you can layout your boxview correctly. (Might also work with the SizeChanged of the content page or another even on absolutelayout that i dont know about right now)

Comment: But it kinda feels like you can solve this with a grid. Add a column to it with an absolute width and a row with a "star"-sized height